# php/mysql basic search not returing results

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have a test query I am performing and it seems to be running OK, however not returning any data within the rows of the tables when using a varible passed or a direct set year for the table

```
    <?
$curyr = date("Y");
isset($_GET['year']) ? $year = $_GET['year'] : $year = "";
$server = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuname = "";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "";
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuname,$dbpass,$dbname);

if($conn->connect_errno):
    die("$conn->connect_error \n");
endif;

echo ("<title>$year</title>");

if (($year >= 2001) && ($year <=$curyr)) {
echo ("
<table border='0' align='center' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border='1' align='center' width='60%' style='border:1 solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse'>
                <tr>
                    <th align='center' colspan='5'>
                            DETAIL
                    </th>
                </tr>");
                $query = "SELECT c.* , p.* FROM $year c, dataset p WHERE c.id = p.id ORDER BY p.name ASC";
                $r = $conn->query($query);
                while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo ("
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;$row[namepre]$row[name]
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        TEST
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>");
                }
            echo ("
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>");
} else {
    echo ("ERROR NO ROWS");
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I'm returning the "detail" portion of the top of the sample table but nothing else. This is just basic but wondering where I'm possibly missing something.

Comment: Not sure if related to the problem, but I think you may need curly brackets around the array variables in your echo: {$row['namepre']}.

Comment: Oh, and I also you may need to use backtick quotes around the table name if it's all digits. I am not sure if it being a variable handles that already, but maybe something to check.

Comment: Please learn to use ANSI JOIN syntax instead of cross products in your queries.

Comment: i plan on using a join in the future .. but this is just quick and dirty, nothing for anything but a test and quick check .. and yes it was a forgotten back tick .. always something simple ..

Comment: A table that references a specific year can be symptomatic of poor design